# Rutas personalizadas en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy tratando de personalizar algunas rutas de mis páginas de wordpress pero estoy teniendo un problema.

Con un ejemplo se verá fácil:

```
Lo que Wordpress me permite: dominio.com/page1
```

```
Lo que yo quiero hacer: dominio.com/loquesea/page1
```

Cuando intento hacerlo me sustituye la / por un -

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes usar un parent, por ejemplo crea una pagina llamada test de ejemplo, tendras, dominio.com/test luego crea una pagina llamada test page por ejemplo y a test page donde dice parent asígnale la pagina test, entonces tendras dominio.com/test/test-page aunque la forma correcta seria usando add_rewrite_endpoint() y otras funciones, pero tendrás que leer documentación para eso.

Comment: No te doy una respuesta clara pues a tu pregunta le falta trabajo de investigación, por lo que te invito a leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y hacer el [tour]